# Laravel Assert Redirect Ignoring Query Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, testing, assertion

I have an api test that asserts for redirect to a specific route. The issue is the redirect url has query parameters that includes a timestamp which changes. Wondering if Laravel's assertions has an an alternative to assertRedirect method that ignores query parameters.

```
/** @test */
    public function test_can_redirect()
    {

        $this->call('GET', "users/auth")
            ->assertRedirect('http://localhost:8000/dashboard?timestamp=1550848436');
    }
```

I want to assert a redirect to

```
http://localhost:8000/dashboard
```

not

```
http://localhost:8000/dashboard?timestamp=1550848436
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly? This value is dynamic? Just strip it out of the string before passing it to assertRedirect.

Comment: `->assertRedirect('http://localhost:8000/dashboard');` ?

Comment: The assertRedirect method would compare 
http://localhost:8000/dashboard
to
http://localhost:8000/dashboard?timestamp=1550848436
and return false

Comment: The timestamp is included in the uri comparison when using assertRedirect

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem, I want to assert the redirect location has a given query string parameter but it seems to be missing, the `$response->headers->get('Location')`  has no query string parameters at all..

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getTargetUrl` to extract what is without query string.

```php
public function test_can_redirect()
{
    $redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/dashboard';
    $res = $this->getJson('users/auth')->assertStatus(302); # Check if redirection
    # Or you could use this: $this->assertTrue($res->isRedirection());
    $parts = explode('?', $res->getTargetUrl());
    $this->assertTrue($parts[0] === $redirectUrl); # parts[0] is the url 
wihtout query string

    # If you want to check the keys of query string, too
    $this->assertTrue(count($parts) === 2);  # check query string exists
    parse_str($parts[1], $query);
    $this->assertArrayKeys($query, ['time', ..., 'the key you want to check']);
}

protected function assertArrayKeys(array $array, array $checks) 
{
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach ($checks as $check) {
        $this->assertTrue(in_array($check, $keys));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The principle behind testing your code is to make sure that what is happening is what is expected, so if you are expecting the query parameter of a timestamp, why not build it up too?

```
/** @test */
    public function test_can_redirect()
    {
        $url = "/dashboard";
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
        $timestamp = time();

        $this->call('GET', "users/auth")
            ->assertRedirect($url . '?timestamp=' . $time);
    }
```

Comment: The timestamp generated in your test and the one generated form the controller will still differ.. time is not constant